# python log unexpectedly prints the indentation

Tags: python, logging

The code is as below:

```
self.class_logg('http://example.com/api/?\
                option=ajax&nologin=1&a=vmware_migrate_2&\
                original_server_ip=%s&target_server_ip=%s&\
                vmware_name=%s' % (self.ip, dest_node.ip, machine.name))
```

Because this string is so long, i have to split it into those several lines, but unfortunately find that in the log it prints like this:

```
http://example.com/api/?option=ajax            &nologin=1&a=vmware_migrate_2            &original_server_ip=192.168.0.224$
```

Apparently it prints the indentation spaces there. How to resolve this problem?
the self.class_logg is just there for example, in my case the problem happens even if it is print.

Comment: Thanks, thefourheye. I found it was wrong about the format, and because i missed a blank line in front of the code block. I was trying to edit it, but you was faster than me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove the `\`

```
self.class_logg(('http://example.com/api/?'
                 'option=ajax&nologin=1&a=vmware_migrate_2&'
                 'original_server_ip=%s&target_server_ip=%s&'
                 'vmware_name=%s' % (self.ip, dest_node.ip, machine.name)))
```

In Python, when strings are next to each other in the code, it will combine them. It is called "string grouping"

---

However, it seems to me that you would do better with a dictionary:

```
fields = {'option': 'ajax',
          'nologin': '1',
          'a': 'vmware_migrate_2',
          'original_server_ip': self.ip,
          'target_server_ip': dest_node.ip,
          'vmware_name': machine.name}

params = '&'.join(['{}={}'.format(k, v) for k, v in fields.items()])
self.class_logg('http://example.com/api/?{}'.format(params))
```

If the order is important (which it should not be) You can use an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), or a list of tuples.

Answer (score 1):

You should use grouping instead of concatanation or any other line braking:

```
self.class_logg('http://example.com/api/?'
                'option=ajax&nologin=1&a=vmware_migrate_2&'
                'original_server_ip=%s&target_server_ip=%s&'
                'vmware_name=%s' % (self.ip, dest_node.ip, machine.name))
```

*Personal recommendation: you should use* `format` *instead of* `%`:

```
self.class_logg(('http://example.com/api/?'
                 'option=ajax&nologin=1&a=vmware_migrate_2&'
                 'original_server_ip={}&target_server_ip={}&'
                 'vmware_name={}').format(self.ip, dest_node.ip, machine.name))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a handy trick that arises from how Python handles adjacent string constants:

```
self.class_logg('http://example.com/api/?'
                'option=ajax&nologin=1&a=vmware_migrate_2&'
                'original_server_ip=%s&target_server_ip=%s&'
                'vmware_name=%s' % (self.ip, dest_node.ip, machine.name))
```

When Python sees two string constants immediately adjacent, it automatically joins them together to make a single string constant. This includes across lines, as long as Python recognizes that the next line is a continuation of the previous (which it will in this case, since you're inside a pair of parentheses).

You can see this in action with a simple example:

```
>>> print ('abc'
           'def'
           'ghi')
abcdefghi
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is one huge string with tabulations. Split in four *different* strings like so:

```
self.class_logg('http://example.com/api/?'\
            'option=ajax&nologin=1&a=vmware_migrate_2&'\
            'original_server_ip=%s&target_server_ip=%s&'\
            'vmware_name=%s' % (self.ip, dest_node.ip, machine.name))
```

What matters are the single quotes in the start of every single string.